# How to convert user-string-input into conditions to pass as parameters to Python Pandas' drop function?

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

In pandas if you want to drop some rows based on conditions, you can do something like:

```
df = df.drop(df[(df.score < 50) & (df.score > 20)].index)
```

The main varying part is the followings which signifies the conditions:

```
(df.score < 50) & (df.score > 20)
```

I am trying to create my own function based off of this.

```
def drop_condition(df, cond_in_str):
    df.drop(df[cond_in_str].index, inplace=True)
```

And to call it like so:

```
drop_condition(df, 'df.score < 50')
KeyError: 'df.score < 50'
```

How can I convert a string of condition into parameter condition the Pandas drop function will recognize?

Comment: Those conditions are not string. You are passing them as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your function as-is, just without the quotes:

```
drop_condition(df, df.score < 50)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**pandas.DataFrame.query()**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) which takes the expression as a `string`.

```
def drop_condition(df, cond_in_str):
      df.drop(df.query(cond_in_str).index)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating another variable and assigning to it ? and then using in function

```
check_val = df.score > 50
(drop_condition(df, check_val))
```